# copy and morph several worksheets into one worksheet for pivot

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to combine several worksheets into one worksheet via VBA to resolve a matrix type into a pivot friendly form. This works nicely so far, except for the fact that after each loop one additional line gets appendended.

Here is what I get:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRNXz.png)

And this is what i would like to have:

[Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwZch.png)

```
Public Sub CopyData()

Dim iRowCount, iTableCount, iRowCountTarget, iColumnCount, iRowCountUser, iWorksheetsCounter, iNumberOfWorksheets As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


iColumnCount = 2
iRowCountUser = 1

iWorksheetsCounter = 1
iNumberOfWorksheets = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1


iTableCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
iTableCountTarget = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(iNumberOfWorksheets + 1).Range("A:A"))


For iWorksheetsCounter = 1 To iNumberOfWorksheets


    For iRowCount = 1 To iTableCount

      With ActiveWorkbook

       .Worksheets(iNumberOfWorksheets + 1).Cells(iTableCountTarget + 1, 3) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(iWorksheetsCounter).Cells(iRowCountUser, iColumnCount)

       .Worksheets(iWorksheetsCounter).Cells(iRowCount + 1, 1).Copy
       .Worksheets(iNumberOfWorksheets + 1).Cells(iTableCountTarget + 1, 1).PasteSpecial

       .Worksheets(iWorksheetsCounter).Cells(iRowCount + 1, 2).Copy
       .Worksheets(iNumberOfWorksheets + 1).Cells(iTableCountTarget + 1, 2).PasteSpecial

       .Worksheets(iNumberOfWorksheets + 1).Cells(iTableCountTarget + 1, 4) = iTableCountTarget

      End With

      iTableCountTarget = iTableCountTarget + 1


    Next iRowCount

Next iWorksheetsCounter


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

where am I adding the additional line? I cannot seem to get around it.

thanks for all the pointers!

EDIT: Added a picture of the source table upon request.
All tables should be the same size, but I might want to extend that to more columns in individual tables later down the line

[Source Table(s)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu0js.png)

Comment: Do you have headers? COUNTA might be adding one for that reason.

Comment: Yea, i do have headers. I naively removed them just now, expecting a different result, which it obvs. did not. thanks for the hint though

Comment: Your code looks rather complicated for what it's doing. Is each source table the same size? Could you attach a picture of one of them please?

Comment: yea - i am just dusting off my old VBA knowledge and getting started with some automation. It defo is not the most elegant or efficient of code. I'll add a picture of the table right away.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it :

```
Dim oWs, oFinalWs As Worksheet
Dim finalLastRow As Integer

Set oFinalWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("final")
oFinalWs.Cells.ClearContents

For Each oWs In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not oWs.Name = oFinalWs.Name Then
        finalLastRow = oFinalWs.Cells(oFinalWs.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        oWs.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Copy oFinalWs.Cells(finalLastRow, 1)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion - as mentioned in my previous comment to @SJR I am only just dusting off my old VBA knowledge. I am sure, what you provided is elegant and efficient, only I am having a hard time understanding it right off the bat.